# Project Online 2013 JSOM Napa - Cannot find resource for the request ProcessQuery

Tags: project-server, client-object-model

I'm trying to build a very simple JSOM app using Napa, that would list the projects created, but I'm getting the following exception:

```
Unexpected response from server. The status code of response is '500'. The status text of response is 'Internal Server Error'.

Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ResourceNotFoundException
Cannot find resource for the request ProcessQuery
```

Here's a piece of my code:

Default.aspx

```
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/ps.js"></script>
...
```

App.js

```
// Declare global variables.
var projContext;
var projects;

$(document).ready(function () {
    SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(GetProjects, "ps.js");
});

// Get the projects collection.
function GetProjects() {

    // Display a message to the user to show we are reading the projects. 
    $('#spanMessage').text('Reading projects...');

    // Initialize the current client context.
    projContext = PS.ProjectContext.get_current();

    // Get the projects collection.
    projects = projContext.get_projects();

    // Register the request for information that you want to run on the server.
    projContext.load(projects);

    // Run the request on the server.
    projContext.executeQueryAsync(IterateThroughProjects, QueryFailed);
}

function IterateThroughProjects(response) {
    // Get the enumerator and iterate through the collection.
    var enumerator = projects.getEnumerator();
    while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
        var project = enumerator.get_current();

        // Get the target project and then check it out. The checkOut function
        // returns the draft version of the project.
        var draftProject = project.checkOut();

        // Specify "true" to also check the project in.
        var publishJob = draftProject.publish(true);

        // Register the job that you want to run on the server and specify the
        // timeout duration and callback function.
        projContext.waitForQueueAsync(publishJob, 30, QueueJobSent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it! Had to ensure that the PS.js file was loaded before the custom code runs, and the ProjectContext was initialized.
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

That last answer was useless. I'll start fresh with some possibilities:

First, in your Script On-Demand method in your doc ready, you're not explicitly saying to wait for the CSOM library to finish loading. Try using this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', GetProjects);
});
```

Next, for your registrations in your default.aspx, make sure these three are referenced in this order: (I still don't think you need to explicitly reference sp.js)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.debug.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.debug.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/ps.debug.js"></script>
```

If neither of those produce results, then I think the error is still in your context setup. I don't have a Project Server instance to test against but I would explore the notion of app context versus host context.

Comment: Hi Josey, thanks for the quick response. Actually, I've opened the solution in VS2012 and there is a method get_projects(). Please note that I am asking get_projects() to a ProjectContext (not ClientContext). Also, do I need to reference sp.debug.js or just ps.js? Thanks

Comment: Josey, I've updated my question. It seems there's an error when I try to run the request on the server. More precisely, this is the line that fails: `projContext.executeQueryAsync`

Comment: Ah, I see. I breezed right over the first word of your title and thought projects was a mere list; not Project Server. My bad.  I'll edit my answer to remove the misinformation. But as for a solution to your issue, I think the answer still lies in your context setup. Try setting the context using the getQueryStringParameter function.

Comment: Josey, I finally fixed it. Had to ensure that the PS.js file was loaded before the custom code runs, and the ProjectContext was initialized.